# How can i convert SQL (using postgreSQL) to sequelize query in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a SQL query (using postgreSQL) that I need to write as a sequelize query in node.js.

Query:

````
select rd.id AS question_id, count(1) as viewCount,max(vl.timestamp) AS last_viewed, cu.email, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, rd.name as CardName, rd.description as DashboardDescription 
from core_user cu 
INNER JOIN view_log vl on vl.user_id = cu.id 
INNER JOIN report_card rd on rd.id  = vl.model_id
where vl.model='card' 
GROUP BY cu.email, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, rd.name, rd.description, rd.id 
ORDER BY last_viewed DESC```
````

Comment: Please add model definitions and associations